# Python, How do I change the directory locally?

Tags: python

When changing directory with the OS module , the change is made globally. Is there a way to change directory locally?

EDIT:Yea, sorry . Locally in another thread. The normal chdir changes the working directory over all threads when you use the thread module.

Comment: What do you mean "locally" and "globally" here? There's only one current working directory, as far as I know.

Comment: We can't really answer your question until you clear up what you mean by your terms? Is about CWD in a multi-threaded program?

Comment: Yea , in multi threading , sorry forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very difficult to write a decorator/context-manager to do this using [`contextlib2.contextmanager`](http://contextlib2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

```
import contextlib2
import os

@contextlib2.contextmanager
def restore_chdir(dir_):
    orig= os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(dir_)
    try: 
        yield
    finally: 
        os.chdir(orig)
```

You can use this now as:

```
with restore_chdir('/foo'):
    ...
```

or as a function decorator.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a function with `os` module, which can restore the directory.

```
import os
def func():
  original = os.getcwd()
  os.chdir("Your Directory Name")
  ## Do something here
  os.chdir(original)
```